# Can all clothes get wet?

Tags: senran-kagura-estival-versus

After playing on the Tropical Beach stage as Katsuragi, I noticed on the victory screen that her default shinobi outfit had become wet and see-through, assumingly from me jumping in the ocean.

Since I hadn't seen this effect before, even after spending time in the water as other characters, I'm wondering: can only specific outfits get wet? If so, which?

Comment: I don't think so, even in Peach Beash Splash most of the old shinobi clothes don't get wet they just get shredded like in the other games. Never noticed wet clothes being a significant thing before PBS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning: all pictures in this answer have been hidden behind links, as they are NSFW. Click at your own risk.*

## All clothes can get wet, with some nuances.

In order for clothes to get wet, the character needs to get knocked into a body of water (the ocean, hot springs, baths...) and **not perform any action to accelerate her recovery** like a wake-up attack or an evade. The exact trigger seems to be the character beginning their "getting up" animation, marked by a voice line, after which it's safe to evade, jump, or perform any other action. Clothes don't seem to get wet on the first try every time, sometimes requiring two or more dips into water.

However, not all clothes become see-through. To test this, I started with the Hanzo Academy uniform, which I'd personally experienced could become see-through: [dry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvTwC.jpg) and [wet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXYEH.jpg).
Next, I tried the same uniform in a different colour, which did not become see-through: [dry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uohPE.jpg) and [wet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDRjc.jpg).
I then tried a different recolour that kept the white blouse, which [did end up becoming see-through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjReU.jpg).

I then moved to the Gessen Academy uniform, which is normally black, and [did not become see-through when wet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz4B2.jpg). Interestingly, the uniform didn't become see-through [when I changed to its white recolour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilig.jpg).

I decided to try a different uniform that's naturally white, the Sailor Uniform. However, neither the [default colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGopJ.jpg) nor [a different white recolour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBv5f.jpg) became see-through. Homura's Jeans & T-Shirt, though, has no trouble [becoming see-through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbJ9L.jpg), as long as it's not in a [different colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYC4h.jpg).

The general rule seems to be that for an outfit to become see-through, it must be white and must be one of the characters' default outfits; this is evidenced by the Sailor Uniform above, as well as [Ryouki's Outfit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnl7z.jpg) being see-through while the [Girl's One-Piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE6qm.jpg) is not. Additionally, if an outfit can become see-through, any alternate colour that stays mostly white can also become see-through.

As a side note, finishing a mission while wet will also have an effect on the menu screen: it makes all of the characters turn from [dry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6BsG.jpg) to [wet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBPPg.jpg).